# Ensure nil or null value when objects deallocate at runtime

Tags: memory-management, compiler-construction, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting

**Reference Counting & ARC Perspective**
In Swift or Objective-C, if the reference counter become zero, the object is deallocated and every pointer values pointing to the object (including the weak variables or properties) become NULL.
How do they do that?

**Manual Memory Management Perspective**
In C or C++, if we free the memory, it only free the memory. If we want it to be NULL, we manually assign NULL. Only pay for what we need and we don't get extra.

**Auto GC perspective**
In Java, VM monitor object reference usages with time intervals and collect them. Setting null value won't be necessary. But there is a type `WeakReference` that does allow Collector to ignore certain objects during marking phase while it is referencing.

My question is that, from a compiler or VM perspective, how do one ensure `nil` or `null` value to be assigned to variables that was previously referencing the object?

Comment: This is *way* to broad. But anyway, it's not generally possible unless you design the language and VM with that in mind. The VM doesn't really have the actual *variables* that reference objects, only the objects themselves and their reference counter..

Comment: Just do it! I mean, I don't get your question :/ you just can free/deallocate your object and then set the pointer to 0. What is the problem at all?

Comment: For Swift, see for example https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html.

Comment: I doubt that “if the reference counter become zero, the object is deallocated and every pointer values pointing to the object … become NULL” is a valid description of the general operation. After all, the underlying assumption is that there are no remaining pointers when the counter reaches zero, so why should the implementation waste time searching for some to set them to NULL. So the issue of clearing pointers *only* applies *weak* references and similar, which is a special case of garbage collection.

Comment: @Holger thanks. By the way , the link MartinR mention has things explained for Swift compiler. I can now go on.

Comment: Yes, that’s an interesting article. For memory management using traversal, like with Java, the task is even easier. During the traversal, it will remember all encountered `WeakReference` instances by linking them, afterwards, it runs through that linked list once and clears them, if their referent has not been encountered during the traversal, or unlinks them otherwise. Then, the list is handed over to another thread which will enqueue the cleared reference objects, if they are associated with a `ReferenceQueue`. That enqueuing can happen concurrently to the application.

Comment: @Holger Can you please share some article, blog or link of this kind related with GC languages. I love to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As [Holger says in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218704/ensure-nil-or-null-value-when-objects-deallocate-at-runtime#comment91393558_52218704), the question is not really phrased properly.  Your question also presupposes *reference count* based collection, which does not quite work for circular data structures, e.g.:

```
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, next = None):
        self.next = next
    def set_next(self, next):
        self.next = next
...
e1 = LinkedList()
e2 = LinkedList(e1)
e1.set_next(e2)
```

(expressed in Python).  What is the reference count for e1, when e1.next.next is also e1 so that e1.next.next.next is e1, and so on?  (Or, more simply, what if we set e1.next to e1 itself?)

Traditional Lisp garbage collection started with [Mark and Sweep algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mark-and-sweep-garbage-collection-algorithm/) (NB: I have no idea whether this web site is good generally, but I scanned the linked article and it seems fine).  Modern systems often have fancier schemes, such as generational collection, "live" (threaded) collection instead of stop-and-go, and real-time collection.  See [the main wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) and especially the rather more comprehensive [Tracing Garbage Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection) article.

Note that the key difference between a strong reference and a weak reference is that a strong reference *is* counted in liveness analysis—i.e., in determining whether to keep some object around because some other object wants it—and a weak reference does not.  The most classic example I know of where one wants a weak reference is in a *lookup cache*, where there is some complex data structure, such as an on-disk B-tree based database or similar, where some objects may be brought into memory to use for a while, and we would like to have a quick way to find out whether they are still available: `dictionary[key]` would be a fast but *weak reference* to the object, while `database.load(key)` returns a *strong reference* to the object, possibly after loading it.

Many implementation details stem from issues like whether and how the language itself allows you to take and work with pointers.  Languages with pointer manipulation (such as C++) make it difficult to do compile-time analysis that other languages (such as Go) make easier.

[Mike Ash's blog](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html), from [Martin R's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218704/ensure-nil-or-null-value-when-objects-deallocate-at-runtime#comment91386131_52218704), has a nice summary of several of these issues and actual implementations, including two used in Swift.

The Go language uses [*escape analysis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) to allocate some objects on the stack and others in a garbage-collected heap.